# How to specify predictor and predicted variables in Golearn

Tags: go, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to use Golearn, which is great, as a machine learning library. I have very simple questions, for which I could not find answers, neither if the library doc, nor on Google:

**How to specify the predictor and predicted variables in a fit ?**
In a linear regression, one can compute Y = aX + b, or X = aY+b.
How does one specify to Golearn which column of the data set is X and which is Y ?

Comment: Hey, you got any solution regarding this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63545696/13717851) out.