# Golearn models are implicit about independent variables (predictors) and targets (predicted)

Tags: go, machine-learning

I am learning ML in Go. I was exploring Golearn Package in Go, for ML support. I am very confused with the way the model.fit and model.predict functions are implemented.

For example in [this example implementation](https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/blob/master/examples/knnclassifier/knnclassifier_iris.go) of Knn Classifier from [Golearn](https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn) repo:

```
    rawData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("../datasets/iris_headers.csv", true)
    
    cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("euclidean", "linear", 2)

    trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(rawData, 0.50)
    cls.Fit(trainData)

    predictions, err := cls.Predict(testData)
```

I am confused which are x and y for model. How do I selectively pass in the predictors and predicted? I have almost got frozen with the internet articles giving no clues about it.

I am new to Golang ML dev. Had prev experience with web and database work in go. I code ML models in python. Recently I found GO is faster in data processing, and suited for ML application while faster than python. I am eager about an explanation of this. If not, a Go library with less complex but sufficient ML support will also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`golearn` ->`knn` implements k nearest neighbor algorithm. It is implemented by

- parsing a csv file into a matrix
- (`Predict` function) calculating distance between vectors using different algorithms

  - euclidian
  - manhattan
  - cosine

  while doing this step all **non numerical fields are removed**. The non numerical field is assumed as label for which this model is training.
- Categories/Labels or `Attributes` defined in `csv`, are returned in  prediction list, a pair of values of the form `(index,predicted Attribute)`.

---

> How do I selectively pass in the predictors and predicted

in `knn` you can do that by labeling your prediction target in csv as a non integer value. For example (`Iris-setosa`,`Iris-versicolor`).

---

linear regression

you can use `AddClassAttribute()`, this method is defined on `DenseInstances` struct which is the output of `base.ParseCSVToInstances()` method.

the code to do that would look like

```
   instances, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("../examples/datasets/exams.csv", true) // true: means first line of csv is headers.
   
   attrArray:=instances.AllAttributes() 
   instances.SetClassAttribute(attrArray[4])//setting final column as class attribute, note that there cannot be more than one class attribute for linear regression.
   trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(instances, 0.1) 
   lr := NewLinearRegression()
   err := lr.Fit(instances)
   if err!=nil{
      // error handling
   }
   predictions, err := lr.Predict(testData)
   if err!=nil{
      // error handling
   }
```

caveat:-> in the test file given with linear regression all these are not done. I would not claim that the above method is the correct way or the optimal way of assigning the regression target.

It is a possible way. It makes a candidate for `Fit()` function of linear regression which is where the computations for this model takes place. `Predict()` function merely multiplies the finite set of linear regression coefficients and stores that value as the prediction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Any idea how the parsing works for linear regression? All columns are numerical there. Also any doc for these details?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to learn these stuff about Go ML library, esp Golearn? I am very interested about go and want to do ML in go, after having a good hand in python.

Comment: I would recommend the book [The Go Programming Language By Alan A. A. Donovan · Brian W. Kernighan](https://www.gopl.io).

Comment: Thanks but I have quite moderate experience with go data structure. I have done go routines, web, database stuff with it. I am looking for well documented ML library, guide or source.